# Multiple Notifications, only the first one fires up

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-alarms

I am making an attendance tracking system.
So, I need to fire notifications before class begins and after class starts.

Main method is where I am creating notifications for each course form a database.

```
mainMethod() {
    testAlarmA(s[0], s[2]);
    testAlarmB(s[0], s[2]);
}
```

I have implemented setAction() method for each intent, and also have different request codes for each pending intent (I have read these in earlier questions on this site)

```
private void testAlarmA (String code) {
    Log.i("attendance", "class-start");
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_ATTENDANCE_NOTIFICATION");
    notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
    notificationIntent.putExtra("type", "start");
    notificationIntent.putExtra("courseCode", code);
notificationIntent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);

    PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 111, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), (2 * 60 * 1000), broadcast);
}

private void testAlarmB (String code){
    Log.i("attendance", "class-end");
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_ATTENDANCE_NOTIFICATION");
    notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
    notificationIntent.putExtra("type", "end");
    notificationIntent.putExtra("courseCode", code);
    notificationIntent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 2);

    PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 222, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), (2 * 60 * 1000), broadcast);

}
```

In by broadcast receiver class, i am extracting extras to know which notification to fire, i.e. class start or end.

But only class start notif is receiver, class end Log Entry is never shown.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i("time", "onReceive");
    mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager = mNotificationManager;

        if (intent.getExtras().containsKey("type")) {
            Log.i("time", "containsKey");

            String type = intent.getExtras().getString("type");
            if (type.equals("end")) {
                Log.i("time", "end");
                endNotif(context);

            } else if (type.equals("start")) {
                Log.i("time", "start");
                startNotif(context);

            } 
     }

}
```

I have also user unique ID for notification builder.

```
private void startNotif (Context context) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle("You Have " + courseCode + " at " + roomNo)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_library_books_white_24dp)
            .setLights(0xff00ff00, 1000, 1000)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
}
```

My end-class notification will have 3 different action buttons.

```
private void endNotif (Context context) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, AttendanceActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("courseCode", courseCode);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    Intent classAttended = new Intent(context, AttendanceNotificationServiceClass.class);
    classAttended.setAction("action");
    classAttended.putExtra("courseCode", courseCode);
    classAttended.putExtra("class", "attended");
    PendingIntent pClassAttended = PendingIntent.getService(context, 11, classAttended, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Intent classBunked = new Intent(context, AttendanceNotificationServiceClass.class);
    classBunked.setAction("action");
    classBunked.putExtra("courseCode", courseCode);
    classBunked.putExtra("class", "bunked");
    PendingIntent pClassBunked = PendingIntent.getService(context, 22, classBunked, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Intent classOff = new Intent(context, AttendanceNotificationServiceClass.class);
    classOff.setAction("action");
    classOff.putExtra("courseCode", courseCode);
    classOff.putExtra("class", "off");
    PendingIntent pClassOff = PendingIntent.getService(context, 33, classOff, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_library_books_white_24dp)
            .setContentTitle(courseCode + " Just Ended")
            .setContentText("Did you attend " + courseCode + " ?")
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_white_24dp, "Attended", pClassAttended)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_thumb_down_white_24dp, "Bucked", pClassBunked)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_clear_white_24dp, "Class Off", pClassOff)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setLights(0xff00ff00, 1000, 1000)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());   
}
```

But when i fire up the app, only class-start notification is shown after 1 minute. class-end notif was supposed to show 1 min after class-start notif.

Start notif is shown as it should be, i.e. after every minute.
But end notif is never shown, not even once.

If in the methods testAlarmA() and testAlarmB(), I make changes such that testAlarmB() is made to fire before testAlarmA(), only B/end will be shown. The A/start will never be shown.

My Log

```
07-14 22:04:49.258 30137-30137/in.ac.iitd.bsw.iitdapp I/time: onReceive
07-14 22:04:49.286 30137-30137/in.ac.iitd.bsw.iitdapp I/time: containsKey
07-14 22:04:49.287 30137-30137/in.ac.iitd.bsw.iitdapp I/time: start
07-14 22:06:29.165 30137-30137/in.ac.iitd.bsw.iitdapp I/time: onReceive
07-14 22:06:29.173 30137-30137/in.ac.iitd.bsw.iitdapp I/time: containsKey
07-14 22:06:29.173 30137-30137/in.ac.iitd.bsw.iitdapp I/time: start
07-14 22:07:59.689 30137-30137/in.ac.iitd.bsw.iitdapp I/time: onReceive
07-14 22:07:59.690 30137-30137/in.ac.iitd.bsw.iitdapp I/time: containsKey
07-14 22:07:59.690 30137-30137/in.ac.iitd.bsw.iitdapp I/time: start
07-14 22:09:52.756 30137-30143/in.ac.iitd.bsw.iitdapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.590ms
07-14 22:10:29.623 30137-30137/in.ac.iitd.bsw.iitdapp I/time: onReceive
07-14 22:10:29.624 30137-30137/in.ac.iitd.bsw.iitdapp I/time: containsKey
07-14 22:10:29.624 30137-30137/in.ac.iitd.bsw.iitdapp I/time: start
07-14 22:11:59.696 30137-30137/in.ac.iitd.bsw.iitdapp I/time: onReceive
07-14 22:11:59.696 30137-30137/in.ac.iitd.bsw.iitdapp I/time: containsKey
07-14 22:11:59.696 30137-30137/in.ac.iitd.bsw.iitdapp I/time: start
07-14 22:13:23.618 30137-30137/in.ac.iitd.bsw.iitdapp I/time: onReceive
07-14 22:13:23.618 30137-30137/in.ac.iitd.bsw.iitdapp I/time: containsKey
07-14 22:13:23.657 30137-30137/in.ac.iitd.bsw.iitdapp I/time: start
07-14 22:15:43.136 30137-30137/in.ac.iitd.bsw.iitdapp I/time: onReceive
07-14 22:15:43.136 30137-30137/in.ac.iitd.bsw.iitdapp I/time: containsKey
07-14 22:15:43.136 30137-30137/in.ac.iitd.bsw.iitdapp I/time: start
```

Answer (score 0):

In testAlarmA and testAlarmB method you are using Intent constructor which is setting action, there is no need of calling setAction again. And in setAction method you are passing Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()), which I think you have inserted by mistake, try removing that.

see this intent constructor:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(java.lang.String)

and setAction method:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setAction(java.lang.String)

Comment: I have used `Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis())` in `setAction()`because I read on stackOverflow that each intent should have different and unique setAction - ID, and as the system time will always be unique for each action, thus I have used that.

Comment: I have also tried without `setAction()`, still same result.
Thank You for reply

Answer (score 0):

Hi When creating pendingIntent object make sure each intent has different notification ID as shown below

```
PendingIntent deletePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), notificationId, deleteIntent, 0);
```

where notificationId is when open app you need to pass one and after launch you need to have another one

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the fact, and as you can see, I have different ID for each Pending Intent, i.e. 111 and 222 for first and second one respectively.

`PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 111, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);`

    `PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 222, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);`

ThankYou for reply.